# Magento Observer - $_FILE array empty on file upload from "Account Information"

Tags: magento, file-upload

I want to enable a customer to upload an image on the "Account Information" page in Magento.
I've added

```
<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" />
```

to the form#form-validate on "Account Information" page(template/customer/form/edit.phtml).

I've created a module with event observer for "customer_save_after" and "customer_save_before" events. I put this code inside my event observer method:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES); exit;
```

it fires when needed but the $_FILES array is empty despite of the fact, that a file is submitted.

When I try:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); exit;
```

I get an array of all submitted fields with my "logo" file field in it, submitted as file name. But I need to submit a file, not a name :).

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer. The form needs to contain

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

attribute. Once added $_FILES gets populated.